# Require systemd service to be started before executing init.d script

Tags: systemd, rhel, mount, init

I have a script in /etc/rc.d/init.d/ on a Red Hat 7 system that is provided by a vendor. This script is able to be started and stopped via `systemctl`, but it appears to not actually be a systemd unit file.

The script depends on a drive being mounted on boot by a systemd unit file. However, this init script tries to start before the mount is finished, so it invariably fails.

I have attempted a hack by adding a line to the beginning of the init script, that causes the script to sleep for 30 seconds before the rest of the script executes: `sleep 30`.

However, the sleep functionality does not work all the time.

Is there any way to make this init script depend on the systemd mount unit file being completed? Any better ways to accomplish this task than adding a sleep to the beginning of the init script? Thanks.

Comment: Could you convert the initd script to a systemd service file and then utilize the `RequiresMountsFor=/path/to/mount` or `After=yourmount.mount` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SysV init scripts are auto-converted by systemd into systemd Unit files. See `man systemd-sysv-generator`. You would like to edit the generated Unit to add a suitable dependency for the mount point. You can do this by creating a "drop-in" file with just a few extra lines. If your init file is called, say, `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysysv`, then the generated Unit will be called `mysysv.service`.  Enter the command:

```
sudo systemctl edit mysysv
```

and you should be in your chosen editor (set env variable EDITOR) on a temporary file. Edit the file to contain something like:

```
[Unit]
# default timeout of 90 secs for dir to be mounted
JobTimeoutSec=600
RequiresMountsFor=/path/to/mount
```

and exit the editor cleanly. This creates file `/etc/systemd/system/mysysv.service.d/override.conf`.
When you now start the `mysysv` Unit, this modification will make the job wait upto 600 seconds until the mount point has something mounted on, before starting.  Otherwise it fails with a timeout.
The default wait time for a job is a system global value of 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

here is a bare bone template systemd file

```
#!/bin/bash

[Unit]
Description=license administration
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/root/scripts/administration.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

- name the above `my_administration.service` for example
- locate it in `/etc/systemd/system/`
- having permissions `root.root` and `-rw-r--r--`
- then do a `systemctl daemon-reload`
- then do a `systemctl list-unit-files` and you will see `my_administration.service` listed
- do a `systemctl enable my_administration`
- after boot, given the above syntax, the file `/root/scripts/administration.sh` will be executed, once the `default.target` run level is reached, which is graphical.target in my case per `systemctl get-default`
- my `administration.sh` file has permissions `root.root` and `-rwx------`; it must be executable *obviously* and that file I manually create; that's my custom little script to do stuff after linux has fully booted.

look at other systemd service files as a reference

refer to redhat system administrator's guide, Chapter 10. Managing Services with systemd

you want to make use of

```
[Unit]
Before=
Wants=
After=
Requires=
```

to get it whatever your `ExecStart=` file is to happen at a certain time... before other services start and definitely after certain services have started.  And not just these four, there are many others which you'll have to look up in the system administrator's guide which you made need to use to make what you want happen happen, those four are just the most commonly used.

you can find all the service files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` to use as a reference.

also check out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

**ALSO:** in your script, you also might be able to do something like

```
if mountpoint -q /bkup ;then /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily; fi
```

In my `/etc/crontab` where I do a daily backup by running *rsnapshot* I first do a `mountpoint -q` to make sure my 10tb backup is mounted and that I don't backup to an unmounted folder on the root partition and crash my system.